# Apache Superset Configuration in local machine not loading properly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dashboard, docker-container, apache-superset

Tried configuring the Superset in local machine, but it ends up with broken links and images as attached below..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTRC6.png)

Tried increasing the RAM size in docker preferences and also tried removing all the existing containers and volume and rebuild it, but the issue still remains the same.

Here by attached the terminal message,

```
    A Default SECRET_KEY was detected, please use superset_config.py to override it.
    superset_init            | Use a strong complex alphanumeric string and use a tool to help you generate 
    superset_init            | a sufficiently random sequence, ex: openssl rand -base64 42
    superset_init            | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    superset_init            | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    superset_init            | 2022-08-25 06:18:59,927:INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
    superset_init            | 2022-08-25 06:18:59,954:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type 
    superset_worker_beat     | [2022-08-25 06:19:00,014: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task reports.scheduler (reports.scheduler)
    superset_worker          | [2022-08-25 06:19:00,041: INFO/MainProcess] Task reports.scheduler[9e6d7309-2a70-4ca7-82be-e5c96e8aa206] received
    superset_node            | npm WARN config optional Use `--omit=optional` to exclude optional dependencies, or
    superset_node            | npm WARN config `--include=optional` to include them.
    superset_node            | npm WARN config 
    superset_node            | npm WARN config     Default value does install optional deps unless otherwise omitted.
    superset_node            | npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
    superset_worker          | [2022-08-25 06:19:00,184: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task reports.scheduler[9e6d7309-2a70-4ca7-82be-e5c96e8aa206] succeeded in 0.13767425700007152s: None
    superset_init            | /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/models/sqla/interface.py:68: SAWarning: relationship 'SqlaTable.slices' will copy column tables.id to column slices.datasource_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'Slice.table' (copies tables.id to slices.datasource_id). If this is not the intention, consider if these relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only. For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the columns that should be written towards.   To silence this warning, add the parameter 'overlaps="table"' to the 'SqlaTable.slices' relationship. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/qzyx)
    superset_init            |   for prop in class_mapper(obj).iterate_properties:
    superset_init            | 2022-08-25 06:19:09,924:INFO:superset.utils.database:Creating database reference for examples
    superset_init            | 2022-08-25 06:19:11,021:DEBUG:superset.models.core:Database.get_sqla_engine(). Masked URL: postgresql://superset:XXXXXXXXXX@db:5432/superset
    superset_app             | 127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2022 06:19:24] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    superset_app             | 2022-08-25 06:19:24,675:INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2022 06:19:24] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Commands tried :

```
    docker compose down -v
    docker compose up
```

But it works well with the non-dev environment with the following command:

```
    docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml pull
    docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up
```

Hereby attached the docker-compose.yml file

```
    #
    # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    # contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    # this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    # The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    # (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    # the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #

    #    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    #
    # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    # limitations under the License.

    #
    x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:${TAG:-latest-dev}
    x-superset-user: &superset-user root
    x-superset-depends-on: &superset-depends-on
      - db
      - redis
    x-superset-volumes: &superset-volumes
      # /app/pythonpath_docker will be appended to the PYTHONPATH in the final container
      - ./docker:/app/docker
      - ./superset:/app/superset
      - ./superset-frontend:/app/superset-frontend
      - superset_home:/app/superset_home
      - ./tests:/app/tests
    
    version: "3.7"
    services:
      redis:
        image: redis:latest
        container_name: superset_cache
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
          - "127.0.0.1:6379:6379"
        volumes:
          - redis:/data

  

    db:
        env_file: docker/.env
        image: postgres:14
        container_name: superset_db
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
          - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
        volumes:
          - db_home:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    
      superset:
        env_file: docker/.env
        image: *superset-image
        container_name: superset_app
        command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "app"]
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
          - 8088:8088
        user: *superset-user
        depends_on: *superset-depends-on
        volumes: *superset-volumes
        environment:
          CYPRESS_CONFIG: "${CYPRESS_CONFIG}"
    
      superset-websocket:
        container_name: superset_websocket
        build: ./superset-websocket
        image: superset-websocket
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
          - redis
        # Mount everything in superset-websocket into container and
        # then exclude node_modules and dist with bogus volume mount.
        # This is necessary because host and container need to have
        # their own, separate versions of these files. .dockerignore
        # does not seem to work when starting the service through
        # docker-compose.
        #
        # For example, node_modules may contain libs with native bindings.
        # Those bindings need to be compiled for each OS and the container
        # OS is not necessarily the same as host OS.
        volumes:
  

        - ./superset-websocket:/home/superset-websocket
          - /home/superset-websocket/node_modules
          - /home/superset-websocket/dist
        environment:
          - PORT=8080
          - REDIS_HOST=redis
          - REDIS_PORT=6379
          - REDIS_SSL=false
    
      superset-init:
        image: *superset-image
        container_name: superset_init
        command: ["/app/docker/docker-init.sh"]
        env_file: docker/.env
        depends_on: *superset-depends-on
        user: *superset-user
        volumes: *superset-volumes
        environment:
          CYPRESS_CONFIG: "${CYPRESS_CONFIG}"
    
      superset-node:
        image: node:16
        container_name: superset_node
        command: ["/app/docker/docker-frontend.sh"]
        env_file: docker/.env
        depends_on: *superset-depends-on
        volumes: *superset-volumes
    
      superset-worker:
        image: *superset-image
        container_name: superset_worker
        command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "worker"]
        env_file: docker/.env
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on: *superset-depends-on
        user: *superset-user
        volumes: *superset-volumes
        # Bump memory limit if processing selenium / thumbnails on superset-worker
        # mem_limit: 2038m
        # mem_reservation: 128M
    
      superset-worker-beat:
        image: *superset-image
        container_name: superset_worker_beat
        command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "beat"]
        env_file: docker/.env
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on: *superset-depends-on
        user: *superset-user
        volumes: *superset-volumes
    
      superset-tests-worker:
        image: *superset-image
        container_name: superset_tests_worker
        command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "worker"]
        env_file: docker/.env
        environment:
          DATABASE_HOST: localhost
          DATABASE_DB: test
          REDIS_CELERY_DB: 2
          REDIS_RESULTS_DB: 3
          REDIS_HOST: localhost
        network_mode: host
        depends_on: *superset-depends-on
        user: *superset-user
        volumes: *superset-volumes

    volumes:
      superset_home:
        external: false
      db_home:
        external: false
      redis:
        external: false
```

and here is the docker-compose-non-dev.yml file,

```
    #
    # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    # contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    # this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    # The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    # (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    # the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #
    #    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    #
    # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    # limitations under the License.
    #
    x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:${TAG:-latest-dev}
    x-superset-depends-on: &superset-depends-on
      - db
      - redis
    x-superset-volumes: &superset-volumes
      # /app/pythonpath_docker will be appended to the PYTHONPATH in the final container
      - ./docker:/app/docker
      - superset_home:/app/superset_home
    
    version: "3.7"
    services:
      redis:
        image: redis:latest
        container_name: superset_cache
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
          - redis:/data
    
      db:
        env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
        image: postgres:14
        container_name: superset_db
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
          - db_home:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    
      superset:
        env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
        image: *superset-image
        container_name: superset_app
        command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "app-gunicorn"]
        user: "root"
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
          - 8088:8088
        depends_on: *superset-depends-on
        volumes: *superset-volumes
    
      superset-init:
        image: *superset-image
        container_name: superset_init
        command: ["/app/docker/docker-init.sh"]
        env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
        depends_on: *superset-depends-on
        user: "root"
        volumes: *superset-volumes
    
      superset-worker:
        image: *superset-image
        container_name: superset_worker
        command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "worker"]
        env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on: *superset-depends-on
        user: "root"
        volumes: *superset-volumes
    
      superset-worker-beat:
        image: *superset-image
        container_name: superset_worker_beat
        command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "beat"]
        env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on: *superset-depends-on
        user: "root"
        volumes: *superset-volumes
    
    volumes:
      superset_home:
        external: false
      db_home:
        external: false
      redis:
        external: false
```

Is there any alternative way to make it work in the local env?

Comment: Its takes about 5mins for the front end to build. Re run it and wait for a bit.

Comment: @steven , I have waited for more than 20 mins..but it still remains the same.Initially in terminal it shows the error with node and postgres version. Once After I changed it and re run the container ,other than the websocket container everything is running, Is the websocket will be the cause for this broken web page?

Comment: Since you want to do this in the local env, do a pip install, has lesser moving parts. Could help you get it up and running.